# How to correctly create a sitemap on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo, sitemap

I followed [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/start-your-seo-right-with-sitemaps-on-rails/) to create my sitemap.

So in **config/sitemap.rb** I have

```
require 'fog-aws'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "https://www.lapenderiedelhomme.fr"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
  add clients_products_path, :priority => 0.5, :changefreq => 'daily'

  Product.find_each do |prod|
    add clients_product_path(prod),:lastmod => prod.updated_at, :priority => 0.5
  end

end

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::S3Adapter.new(fog_provider: 'AWS',
                                                                    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                                                                    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                                                                    fog_directory: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
                                                                    fog_region: 'eu-west-3')

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.public_path = 'tmp/'
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_host = "https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/"
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.sitemaps_path = 'sitemap/'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.ping_search_engines('https://lapenderiedelhomme.fr/sitemap')
```

in my routes I added

```
get '/sitemap', to: 'clients/pages#sitemap'
```

In my **clients/pages_controller.rb**

I have this method:

```
def sitemap
    redirect_to 'https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml.gz'
end
```

in **public/robot.txt**

```
User-Agent: *
Sitemap: https://www.lapenderiedelhomme.fr/sitemap
```

Once everything is pushed on Heroku I ran this command:

```
heroku run rails sitemap:create --app lapenderie-production
```

And I have this result

```
Running rails sitemap:create on ⬢ lapenderie-production... up, run.6997 (Hobby)
/app/config/initializers/meta_tags.rb:1: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_META
/app/config/initializers/default_meta.rb:1: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_META was here
In '/app/public/':
D, [2019-06-30T16:36:05.675507 #4] DEBUG -- :   Product Load (19.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1000]]
+ sitemap.xml.gz                                          57 links /    1.23 KB
Sitemap stats: 57 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m00s

Pinging with URL 'https://lapenderiedelhomme.fr/sitemap':
  Successful ping of Google
  Successful ping of Bing
```

But when I visit this link `https://lapenderiedelhomme.fr/sitemap`

I have this:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>5DF520C4759DD7A2</RequestId>
<HostId>
v2jM40g++QrfdB5TLtpo6hAwkshUkP6jZbgLXgozOyjuoEX8KlRBvnGaVqE9DzccuR81zZUN+pY=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I've created a write and read folder `sitemap` in my bucket...

Comment: It looks like you have two initializers both trying to declare the same constant. Look more closely at those two files.

Comment: I removed one if the two initializer and I still have the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Is your S3 bucket public? You must authorize public access so it works.